# correlation between 2 sets of variables in a dataframe?

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, statistical-test

I have 89 variables and 300 observations. I want to have a correlation matrix of 9 variable x 80 variables from my dataset. correlate() has focus() function that gives me the required correlation value but not the p values, Is there another function/package to achieve this?
I want to also visualize the correlation data using a corrplot().

Answer (score 0):

The correlate function has an option 'test' that you can change it to TRUE:

```
correlate(data1, data2, test=TRUE)
```